# Does "/dev/null" writes data to SD Card before discarding?

Tags: sd-card, linux, ubuntu

I want to maximize my sd card lifespan and Im wondering if redirecting output to /dev/null will reduce my sd card life.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sending output to `/dev/null` means "throw it away". It has no impact on your SD card at all. Of course, the commands that you're running prior and piping *to* `/dev/null` may well be affecting your SD card.

Answer (score 5):

Anything you redirect to `/dev/null` gets dumped out an airlock. For example if you were to `cat /boot/kernel.img > /dev/null` what's happened is effectively nothing. Of course, `cat /boot/kernel.img` would normally just write to the terminal, which is also only a short-term memory cache on the screen. That never gets written to the SD either. There are generally only very specific instances you might want to write to `/dev/null` for actual benefit. For example, doing first pass video encoding still prodcues an output file. This you can send to `/dev/null` to save writes on the card. When you do the second pass of the encoding then you do the actual writing.

Comment: *effectively nothing*? `cat` will still read! Depending on the source that may effectively touch the network and flush several levels of cache and buffers.

Comment: Ack! Yes, that's right. I meant that in terms of factors affecting SD card life. There may be some tiny, minor wear due to the read, but my point was that in general `cat` here isn't a command that would be reasonably expected to affect SD card life.